# Failed building wheel for dlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, dlib

I tried to install dlib this was the full process in command prompt (had to remove a section so it would fit)
A few of the things ive done so far have been:
-Reinstalled python
-Downloaded Cmake
-Redownloaded and updated visual studio
-Tested on other computers and it works fine
-Tried installing it in the pycharm ide
-Downloaded cuda

```
C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts>pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [382 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      <string>:125: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
      Building extension for Python 3.11.5 (tags/v3.11.5:cce6ba9, Aug 24 2023, 14:38:34) [MSC v.1936 64 bit (AMD64)]
      Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311 -A x64'
      -- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.37.32824.0
      -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.37.32824.0
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      CMake Deprecation Warning at C:/Users/Rourk/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mm75scx7/dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:8 (cmake_minimum_required):
        Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
        CMake.

        Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
        CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


      -- pybind11 v2.10.0
      CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Users/Rourk/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mm75scx7/dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:98 (find_package):
        Policy CMP0148 is not set: The FindPythonInterp and FindPythonLibs modules
        are removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0148" for policy details.  Use
        the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        C:/Users/Rourk/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mm75scx7/dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:50 (find_package)
        C:/Users/Rourk/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mm75scx7/dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Common.cmake:180 (include)
        C:/Users/Rourk/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mm75scx7/dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:200 (include)
      This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

      -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/Rourk/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe (found suitable version "3.11.5", minimum required is "3.6")
      -- Found PythonLibs: C:/Users/Rourk/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/libs/python311.lib
      -- Performing Test HAS_MSVC_GL_LTCG
      -- Performing Test HAS_MSVC_GL_LTCG - Success
      -- Using CMake version: 3.27.6
      -- Compiling dlib version: 19.24.2
      -- Looking for sys/types.h
      -- Looking for sys/types.h - found
      -- Looking for stdint.h
      -- Looking for stdint.h - found
      -- Looking for stddef.h
      -- Looking for stddef.h - found
      -- Check size of void*
      -- Check size of void* - done
      -- Enabling SSE2 instructions
      -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
      -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
      -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
      -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
      -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
      -- Found Threads: TRUE
      CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Users/Rourk/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mm75scx7/dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea/dlib/CMakeLists.txt:628 (find_package):
        Policy CMP0146 is not set: The FindCUDA module is removed.  Run "cmake
        --help-policy CMP0146" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
        set the policy and suppress this warning.

      This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

      CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
      -- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5")
      -- Found CUDA, but CMake was unable to find the cuBLAS libraries that should be part of every basic CUDA install. Your CUDA install is somehow broken or incomplete. Since cuBLAS is required for dlib to use CUDA we won't use CUDA.
      -- DID NOT FIND CUDA
      -- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
      -- Searching for FFMPEG/LIBAV
      -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
      -- PkgConfig could not be found, FFMPEG won't be available
      -- Configuring done (27.3s)
      -- Generating done (0.1s)
      -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Rourk/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mm75scx7/dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-311/Release
      Invoking CMake build: 'cmake --build . --config Release -- /m'
      MSBuild version 17.7.2+d6990bcfa for .NET Framework

      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\external\zlib\gzread.c(319,17): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
        uncompr.c
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\external\zlib\gzwrite.c(212,24): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\external\zlib\gzread.c(400,11): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
        zutil.c
        jaricom.c
        jcapimin.c
        jcapistd.c
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\external\zlib\gzread.c(472,11): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\external\zlib\gzwrite.c(232,21): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
        jcarith.c
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\external\zlib\gzwrite.c(371,11): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
        jccoefct.c
        jccolor.c
        jcdctmgr.c
        jchuff.c
        jcinit.c
        jcmainct.c
        jcmarker.c
        jcmaster.c
        jcomapi.c
        jcparam.c
        jcprepct.c
        jcsample.c
        jdapimin.c
        jdapistd.c
        jdarith.c
        jdatadst.c
        jdatasrc.c
        jdcoefct.c
        jdcolor.c
        jddctmgr.c
        jdhuff.c
        jdinput.c
        jdmainct.c
        jdmarker.c
        jdmaster.c
        jdmerge.c
        jdpostct.c
        jdsample.c
        jerror.c
        jfdctflt.c
        jfdctfst.c
        jfdctint.c
        jidctflt.c
        jidctfst.c
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\external\libjpeg\jdmarker.c(331,5): warning C4996: 'strncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\external\libjpeg\jdmarker.c(654,5): warning C4996: 'strncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
        jidctint.c
        jmemmgr.c
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\external\libjpeg\jerror.c(194,5): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
        jmemnobs.c
        jquant1.c
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\external\libjpeg\jerror.c(196,5): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
        jquant2.c
        jutils.c
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\external\libjpeg\jmemmgr.c(1103,19): warning C4996: 'getenv': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _dupenv_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\external\libjpeg\jmemmgr.c(1106,11): warning C4996: 'sscanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sscanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
        dlib.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\dlib_build\Release\dlib19.24.2_release_64bit_msvc1937.lib
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(541,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
        Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Rourk/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mm75scx7/dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea/tools/python/CMakeLists.txt
        dlib.cpp
        matrix.cpp
        vector.cpp
        svm_c_trainer.cpp
        svm_rank_trainer.cpp
        decision_functions.cpp
        other.cpp
        basic.cpp
        cca.cpp
        sequence_segmenter.cpp
        svm_struct.cpp
        image.cpp
        image2.cpp
        image3.cpp
        image4.cpp
        rectangles.cpp
        object_detection.cpp
        shape_predictor.cpp
        correlation_tracker.cpp
        face_recognition.cpp
        cnn_face_detector.cpp
        global_optimization.cpp
        image_dataset_metadata.cpp
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\..\dlib/image_transforms/assign_image.h(86,45): warning C4018: '>=': signed/unsigned mismatch (compiling source file C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\tools\python\src\image3.cpp) [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\..\dlib/image_transforms/assign_image.h(160,9): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void dlib::impl_assign_image_scaled<out_image_type,src_image_type>(dlib::image_view<out_image_type> &,const src_image_type &,const double)' being compiled [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
                with
                [
                    out_image_type=dlib::numpy_image<int8_t>,
                    src_image_type=dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_image_to_mat<dlib::numpy_image<uint32_t>,uint32_t>>
                ] (compiling source file C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\tools\python\src\image3.cpp)
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\..\dlib/image_transforms/assign_image.h(177,9): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void dlib::impl_assign_image_scaled<dest_image_type,dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_image_to_mat<src_image_type,T>>>(dest_image_type &,const dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_image_to_mat<src_image_type,T>> &,const double)' being compiled [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
                with
                [
                    dest_image_type=dlib::numpy_image<int8_t>,
                    src_image_type=dlib::numpy_image<uint32_t>,
                    T=uint32_t
                ] (compiling source file C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\tools\python\src\image3.cpp)
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\tools\python\src\image3.cpp(27,59): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void dlib::assign_image_scaled<dlib::numpy_image<int8_t>,dlib::numpy_image<uint32_t>>(dest_image_type &,const src_image_type &,const double)' being compiled [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
                with
                [
                    dest_image_type=dlib::numpy_image<int8_t>,
                    src_image_type=dlib::numpy_image<uint32_t>
                ]
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\tools\python\src\image3.cpp(435,35): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'pybind11::array convert_image_scaled<uint32_t>(const dlib::numpy_image<uint32_t> &,const std::string &,const double)' being compiled [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
      C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\dlib\..\dlib/image_transforms/assign_image.h(87,45): warning C4018: '<=': signed/unsigned mismatch (compiling source file C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\tools\python\src\image3.cpp) [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\_dlib_pybind11.vcxproj]
        numpy_returns.cpp
        line.cpp
        gui.cpp
           Creating library C:/Users/Rourk/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mm75scx7/dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-311/Release/Release/_dlib_pybind11.lib and object C:/Users/Rourk/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mm75scx7/dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-311/Release/Release/_dlib_pybind11.exp
        Generating code
        Finished generating code
        _dlib_pybind11.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\_dlib_pybind11.cp311-win_amd64.pyd
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(541,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mm75scx7\dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj]
        Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Rourk/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-mm75scx7/dlib_4136d189bb4d4b96932050b02f403dea/tools/python/CMakeLists.txt
      installing to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
      running install
      running install_lib
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\dlib
      copying build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\dlib\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\dlib
      copying build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\_dlib_pybind11.cp311-win_amd64.pyd -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.
      running install_egg_info
      running egg_info
      writing tools/python\dlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to tools/python\dlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to tools/python\dlib.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'tools/python\dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 434, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 419, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 218, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 399, in run
          self.run_command("install")
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 78, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\install.py", line 708, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_egg_info.py", line 31, in run
          self.run_command('egg_info')
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 318, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 326, in find_sources
          mm.run()
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 548, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 593, in add_defaults
          self.read_manifest()
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 214, in read_manifest
          self.filelist.append(line)
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 485, in append
          path = convert_path(item)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Rourk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-kg7ozogw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\util.py", line 141, in convert_path
          raise ValueError("path '%s' cannot end with '/'" % pathname)
      ValueError: path 'dlib/CMakeLists.txt/' cannot end with '/'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```